# Can I improve my SQL response times?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am executing a query that gets some data from a remote server.

It is a simple select query say

```
select * from opendatasource(----).[Database].[dbo].[Table1]
```

Now Table1 (has 4 columns) contains 15 hundred-thousand records and is growing in size.

On my server where I get the result set of the query it takes around 6 seconds to get the data. It looks slow to me.

**The Table1 has a primary key field of datatype char(28)** and no other index of any kind is defined.

This seems to be the problem.

What might be a possible workaround to make the database do work faster?

Help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What kind of source in `OPENDATASOURCE`?

Comment: What is the network latency between the computers (i.e. from where you fire the SQL and the DB server)?

Comment: Client Statistics on Server shows the following Output       Network Statistics - Number of server roundtrips 1, TDS packets sent from client 1 , TDS packets received from server 304, Bytes sent from client 364, Bytes received from server 1243384, Time Statistics Client processing time 3728, Total execution time 5451, Wait time on server replies 1723

Comment: You should be able to reduce the "wait time on server replies" by moving the client closer to the server in network-distance (roundtrip TCP latency); for reducing "client processing time" you will need to narrow the scope of results return to only the fields and rows that you must query for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pulling whole table. I don't think you can make it faster.

Unless:

- you filter the number of pulled rows (`where` condition)
- add index covering you `where` condition
- limit the number of returned field (`select field1, field2` vs `select *`)
- get faster connection between the client (wherever you run the script) and server